# Assign all numbers between StartingNumber and EndingNumber to collection using flow

Tags: visual-flows

I am trying to setup a flow that allows a user to input two values: `StartingNumber` and `EndingNumber`.

I then what the user to press "Finish" and have all numbers between StartingNumber and EndingNumber to be created as Values within a Collection.

The end goal is to loop through the Collection and create records for each number between the StartingNumber and EndingNumber

How do I iterate through these two numbers and create Collection Values for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need a collection to do this.  To prove this out, I built a flow that creates tasks -- the first named "Task_[StartingNumber]"; the last, "Task_[EndingNumber]", based on the user's input.  Here's how:

- Set up your starting screen with fields for "starting_number" and "ending_number"
- Create a variable, "current_number", and use an Assignment element to set it equal to the "starting number" screen input field.
- Use a decision element to determine whether current_number is greater than ending_number.  If it is, display an "all done" screen.
- If current_number is less than or equal to ending_number, ...
- ...use the Record Create element to generate a Task record
- ...use an Assignment element to add 1 to the current_number value
- ...return to the decision point

[image: Visual Flow, not very "bulkified"]

This works, but there's a problem: GOVERNOR LIMITS!

As sfdcfox pointed out below, this Flow would burn through your DML limit if you were creating > 150 records.  In order to avoid this, we can use [an InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) to call an Apex method from within your Flow.

```
public with sharing class CreateTasks {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Bulk create tasks' description='Create multiple task records and insert them all at once.')
    public static list<Integer> createRecords(List<InfoContainer> containers) {
        Integer numRecordsCreated = 0;
        Integer currentNum;

        List<Task> records = new list<Task>();
        List<Integer> returnVal = new List<Integer>();

        for(InfoContainer c : containers){
            system.debug('Container :: ' + c);
            if(c.startNum == null || c.endNum == null){
                throw new InfoContainerException('startNum and endNum are required.');
            }
            if(c.startNum > c.endNum){
                throw new InfoContainerException('startNum must be greater than or equal to endNum.');
            }

            currentNum = c.startNum;

            while(currentNum <= c.endNum){
                Task record = new Task();
                record.Name = 'Record ' + currentNum;
                records.add(record);

                numRecordsCreated ++;
                currentNum ++;

            }
            returnVal.add(numRecordsCreated);
        }
        insert records;

        return returnVal;
    }

    public class InfoContainer {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Start Number')
        public Integer startNum;

        @InvocableVariable(label='End Number')
        public Integer endNum;

    }

    private class InfoContainerException extends Exception {}

}
```

Use the InvocableMethod just like any other element in your Flow pallete, setting its Start Number and End Number values like this:

[image: Visual Flow with InvocableMethod]

(Not pictured here: A [Flow fault path](https://salesforcedude.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/handling-the-unhandled-fault-in-flow/) to handle exceptions thrown by the InvocableMethod. You should include one!)

Unit Tests:

```
@isTest
public class CreateTasks_Test {

    @isTest
    static void createTasks_happy() {
        List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer> containers = new List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer>();
        CreateTasks.InfoContainer container = new CreateTasks.InfoContainer();
        container.startNum = 1;
        container.endNum = 4;

        containers.add(container);
        List<Integer> returnValue = CreateTasks.createRecords(containers);
        system.assertEquals(returnValue[0], 4);

        confirmTaskCount(4);

    }

    @isTest
    static void createTasks_sad(){
        List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer> containers = new List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer>();
        CreateTasks.InfoContainer container = new CreateTasks.InfoContainer();
        container.endNum = 4;

        containers.add(container);
        system.assert(confirmExceptionThrown(containers));

    }

    @isTest
    static void createTasks_bad(){
        List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer> containers = new List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer>();
        CreateTasks.InfoContainer container = new CreateTasks.InfoContainer();
        container.startNum = 4;
        container.endNum = 1;

        containers.add(container);
        system.assert(confirmExceptionThrown(containers));

    }

    @isTest
    static void createLotsOfTasksInOneTransaction() {
        List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer> containers = new List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer>();
        CreateTasks.InfoContainer container = new CreateTasks.InfoContainer();
        container.startNum = 1;
        container.endNum = 400;

        containers.add(container);
        List<Integer> returnValue = CreateTasks.createRecords(containers);
        system.assertEquals(returnValue[0], 400);

        confirmTaskCount(400);

    }

    @isTest
    static void createTasksBulkified() {
        List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer> containers = new List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer>();
        CreateTasks.InfoContainer container;

        for(Integer i=100; i > 0; i--){
            container = new CreateTasks.InfoContainer();
            container.startNum = 1;
            container.endNum = 4;

            containers.add(container);

        }
        List<Integer> returnValue = CreateTasks.createRecords(containers);
        system.assertEquals(returnValue.size(), 100);

        confirmTaskCount(400);

    }

    private static void confirmTaskCount(Integer expectedCount){
        Integer taskCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Task];
        system.assertEquals(taskCount, expectedCount, taskCount + ' records were found, but we expected to find ' + expectedCount);

    }

    private static Boolean confirmExceptionThrown(List<CreateTasks.InfoContainer> containers){
        try{ 
            CreateTasks.createRecords(containers);

        } catch(CreateTasks.InfoContainerException e){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that DML limits apply, but is probably the best solution given the limitations off low.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- Ooh.  I thought the records would only be written to the database at the end of the flow.  I must have been thinking about the way it works when multiple interviews of the same flow are running in the same execution context.  (Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_bulkification.htm#vpm_admin_bulkification). 

Isn't there a way to create records, add them to a collection, and write them to the DB all at once?

Comment: If you find one, let me know. Last time I tried, I literally had to resort to using an InvocableMethod to achieve decent results. Flow really isn't meant to handle situations like this, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- I'll play with it for a bit.  An invocableMethod might be the way to go.  I'll write one as penance if I can't find a way to do this without code.  ;)  Thanks!

Comment: you'll need a flow fault path as well since invocable is throwing exceptions

Comment: Good call.  I just added a note about including a fault path. Thanks, @cropredy!